# How to write a generic that extracts the prop types of the component that passed in

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can i write a generic that takes in a component and use its prop type as the type of the second parameter

Lets say i pass in a component with the type of `React.FunctionComponent<IMovieShowcase>`

How can i extract the type of `IMovieShowcase`

```
function renderWithProviders<T How to extract type of T<Props>>(
  Component: T, props: // props should be IMovieShowcase
) { 
  return (
    <MemoryRouter>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={createMuiTheme()}>
        <Component {...props} />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use TypeScript's [type inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types).

This `InferProps` accepts the generic named `Component`. So it can be used as `InferProps<YourComponent>` to return the type of the props. As far as I am aware of there is the `ComponentClass` and `FunctionComponent` types that are valid React components. Since we have to handle both we can use a nested conditional (hence the double `?`).

The first conditional statement `Component extends React.ComponentClass<infer Props>` is saying if our `Component` extends a `React.ComponentClass` then `infer` the `Props` and return that type. If it's not, then check `Component extends React.FunctionComponent<infer Props>`. If `Component` extends a `React.FunctionComponent` then `infer` the `Props` and return that type. Otherwise, return `never` because we're not sure how to handle or what it is so we can't infer the props.

```js
type InferProps<
  Component extends ComponentTypes
> = Component extends React.ComponentClass<infer Props>
  ? Props
  : Component extends React.FunctionComponent<infer Props>
  ? Props
  : never;
```

Used in a simplified example with the code you provided:

```js
import * as React from "react";

type ComponentTypes = React.ComponentClass<any> | React.FunctionComponent<any>;

type InferProps<
  Component extends ComponentTypes
> = Component extends React.ComponentClass<infer Props>
  ? Props
  : Component extends React.FunctionComponent<infer Props>
  ? Props
  : never;

function renderWithProviders<T extends ComponentTypes>(
  Component: T,
  props: InferProps<T>
) {
  return <Component {...props} />;
}

class Test extends React.Component<{ foo: string }> {
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

const Another = (props: { baz: number }) => null;

// Valid:
renderWithProviders(Test, { foo: "bar" });

// Valid:
renderWithProviders(Another, { baz: 1 });

// Invalid:
//  Object literal may only specify known properties,
//  and 'baz' does not exist in type '{ foo: string; }'
renderWithProviders(Test, { foo: "bar", baz: "foo" });

// Invalid:
//  The expected type comes from property 'baz' which is
//  declared here on type '{ baz: number; }'
renderWithProviders(Another, { baz: "nope" });
```

[image: Edit infer-props]

Comment: I'm getting `JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.` [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infer-props-1lljx)  how can we type `T`as `React.FC` ?

Comment: @AsafAviv oops, try again?

Comment: Here is a union built-in in React: `type InferProps<C extends React.ComponentType> = C extends React.ComponentType<infer P> ? P : never`